# How can i schedule pyspark script on hourly basis on linux enviroment

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark, job-scheduling

I have one pyspark script and i want that script to be executed on hourly basis means after each hour the script should get executed . 
How can i execute that script on hourly basis .

I've search a lot but didn't get anything.

Comment: with oozie or crontab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of the below approaches

1. https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2017/06/30/scheduling-spark-job-written-pyspark-sparkr-yarn-oozie/
2. https://github.com/pinterest/pinball
3. cron tab
4. http://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html

Comment: Thanks i'll try one of the above approach .